# OTA not working in iOS9

Tags: ios, iphone, plist, ios9

I have created a OTA link by configuring html, plist, ipa files in my server. The link works fine in iOS8 and installs the app in the devices but not working in iOS9. Do i need to add any special key in the plist file for iOS9?

Comment: What do you mean by OTA?

Comment: @AshishKakkad "Over the air". It's a way to install an app for testing.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes. But I want to say that please clarify in the question.

Comment: @indie_iOS Are you seeing anything in the device log when you try to download the file?